# Missing msvcr120.dll during installation

Tags: installation

I'm new to Blender and having trouble installing  it.
It looks like I'm missing "MSVCR120.dll". I've looked on the Blender site and found only closed jobs for this error.  I saw that in the .zip file from the download page it has it included but it still pops the error when trying to start Blender.

Could anyone help and tell me when MSVCR120.dll needs to be installed?

```
Error from win7 x64
24gb ddr3 1600, amd fx8350, twin gtx750TI
```

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH 
  Application Name: blender-app.exe
  Application Version:  2.7.3.0
  Application Timestamp:    54beacf4
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR120.dll
  Fault Module Version: 12.0.21005.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   524f83ff
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000092bc3
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9c5b
  Additional Information 2: 9c5b99d1538af1465d6588ee6e30c6d2
  Additional Information 3: 16bd
  Additional Information 4: 16bd3220bb13198108855400ad31c1a0
```

Comment: Try downloading the blender installer from http://www.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows 7 sp1?
The links below are from posts I found with similar errors in different apps.

Using the Microsoft C Runtime with User-Mode Drivers and Desktop ...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn448963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/missing-msvcr120ddll/28b03b3b-1d15-4e47-ba31-8ace6920b9ba

Installing the run-time and/or making sure you have the latest Windows Updates might help you.